# Why does 7-zip.exe return "Access is denied" with these arguments/parameters?

Tags: permissions, batch, 7-zip

In a batch file:

```
START "7-zip" /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\" "7z.exe" a -o <F:> testArchive F:\test
```

Or, alone on the cmd as:

```
7z.exe a -o <C:\users\user\Desktop> testArc C:users\user\desktop\test
```

returns "Access is denied". I would expect it to run 7-zip with the specified parameters. Why doesn't it?

Here is the code for the batch file:

```
@echo off 
:Variables 
set SOURCE=F:\myDocuments\ 
set DESTINATION=E:\myDocuments\ 
:If disc space is available, make tar ball or .7z or whatever of /myDocuments and place it in F:/Backups 
START "7-zip" /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\" "7z.exe" a -o <F:> testArchive F:\test 
pause 
:echo %SOURCE% 
:echo %DESTINATION% 
:pause 
:run create sync. on documents to H:/myDocuments 
:Otherwise, say there's not enough disc space
```

This doesn't happen if proper syntax is followed for the z-zip command. Access is Denied was due to a 7zip syntax error.

Comment: Are yoou running it as that user or as an admin?

Comment: I've tried both; i.e., right clicking the batch file and selecting 'run as administrator', and running it in an administrator's cmd window.

Comment: Depending on the security on your machine, that may or may not give you access. Try shift right click -> Run as different User then run it as an actual admin account.

Comment: @EBGreen Still getting access is denied. I'm adding more information here: OS is WIN7, the batch file is (a work in progress): `@echo off

:Variables
set SOURCE=F:\myDocuments\
set DESTINATION=E:\myDocuments\


:If disc space is available, make tar ball or .7z or whatever of /myDocuments and place it in F:/Backups

START "7-zip" /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\" "7z.exe" a -o <F:> testArchive F:\test

pause

:echo %SOURCE%
:echo %DESTINATION%
:pause

 :run create sync. on documents to H:/myDocuments

:Otherwise, say there's not enough disc space`

Comment: Ugghh...edit the question and add the new info in there please.

Comment: What is the permission on this file? who is the owner?

Comment: Does the -o parameter not need to be followed by the name of the folder, as in -oe:\mydocuments ?

Answer (score 6):

Check the permissions of the 7za.exe program itself;  Right click -> Properties -> Security -> (choose a user)

And check that Read & Execute is ticked.  On my machine, I had Read access but not Execute.

Comment: if that does not work, do the same for the drive you are launching 7zip

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue randomly. When I add the first file it works fine, but trying to add a new file, then got the "Access denied" message.

I solved it by defining the temp directory (work directory) to 7z. Like:

```
7z a -w"C:\1" "C:\1\zip_file.zip" "C:\1\file_to_zip.txt"
```

Now it will use the work directory as "C:\1" and works fine for me.

Comment: To others reading this: note there must *not* be a space between -w and the following path.

Comment: @Asu i was able to get it to work just now (latest version of 7za) with a space in between. Maybe they've changed that since you commented.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reinstalling 7-Zip in a drive other than system drive

Answer (score 0):

i found that changing the permissions to add "Write" solved my issue. but that leaves me with the question as to WHY NOW?. i have never had this issue before. i had to reset my win 10 due to performance issues. and as such i had to reinstall many applications. 7zip being one of em. never before have i encountered this problem. and i am unsure as to why it happened now.

Comment: You changed the permissions on what?